# When to use custom AccessDecisionManager (need a real use case)

Tags: spring, spring-security

i am just curious
when i will need to use a custom AccessDecisionManager
i need some use cases from your experience guys, if anyone have used it before, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical example given in the [Spring Security docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/authz-arch.html#authz-access-decision-manager) is for customizing voter tallies, like if a particular voter should be weighted more heavily than others.

You could also customize behavior based on, say, properties of the secured object passed in to the `decide` method, for example, based on existing business logic. (That could also be handled by a custom voter, or other means, but if it's generic it might be easier to put it in a decision manager.)

IMO it's *relatively* unusual to need extensive customization at this level, but others may have additional insight.

Answer (score 0):

You also need a custom AcceessDecisionManager if you have complex object for a granted authority, spring default only supports string for that.